# when modifying one sql record it is modifying all the table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to edit only one record in the table via this php code .
But the problem is if the same customer has multiple records in the table , then when I edit one record , the code is editing all the customer records to the one I've edited ..
Let me explain further :
This is the php code I'm using:

```
<?php

// server info
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'mysql';

// connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

function renderForm($customer_name = '', $MGMT_IP = '', $Vendor = '', $Version = '', $GUI_User = '', $GUI_Pass = '', $Notes = '', $error = '', $customer_number = '')
{ ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
<title>
<?php if ($customer_number != '') { echo "edit customer record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?>
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php if ($customer_number != '') { echo "type in the all required fields"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
<?php if ($error != '') {
echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
. "</div>";
} ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<?php if ($customer_number != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="customer_number" value="<?php echo $customer_number; ?>" />
<p>customer_number: <?php echo $customer_number; ?></p>
<?php } ?>

<strong>customer name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="customer_name"
value="<?php echo $customer_name; ?>"/><br/><br/>
<label for="Vendor">vendor</label>
<select name="Vendor">
<option value="Juniper">Juniper</option>
<option value="Fortinet">Fortinet</option>
<option value="Websense">Websense</option>
<option value="F5">F5</option>
<option value="Cisco">Cisco</option>
<option value="Backbox">Backbox</option>
<option value="Radware">Radware</option>
<option value="Orion">Orion</option>
<option value="VM">VM</option>
<option value="EMC">EMC</option>
<option value="Backup">Backup</option>
<option value="HP">HP</option>
<option value="Storage">Storage</option>
<option value="PinApp">PineApp</option>
<option value="RDP">RDP</option>
</select><br/><br/>

<strong>MGMT IP: *</strong> <input type="text" name="MGMT_IP"
value="<?php echo $MGMT_IP; ?>"/><br/><br/>
<strong>version: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Version"
value="<?php echo $Version; ?>"/><br/><br/>
<strong>GUI User: *</strong> <input type="text" name="GUI_User"
value="<?php echo $GUI_User; ?>"/><br/><br/>
<strong>GUI Pass: *</strong> <input type="text" name="GUI_Pass"
value="<?php echo $GUI_Pass; ?>"/><br/><br/>
<strong>notes: </strong> <input type="text" name="Notes"
value="<?php echo $Notes; ?>"/>
<p>* FILLUP REUIRED FIELDS</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php }

/*

EDIT RECORD

*/


{
// if the 'customer_number' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['customer_number']))
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// make sure the 'customer_number' in the URL is valid
if (is_numeric($_POST['customer_number']))
{
// get variables from the URL/form
$customer_number = $_POST['customer_number'];
$customer_name = htmlentities($_POST['customer_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Vendor = htmlentities($_POST['Vendor'], ENT_QUOTES);
$MGMT_IP = htmlentities($_POST['MGMT_IP'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Version = htmlentities($_POST['Version'], ENT_QUOTES);
$GUI_User = htmlentities($_POST['GUI_User'], ENT_QUOTES);
$GUI_Pass = htmlentities($_POST['GUI_Pass'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Notes = htmlentities($_POST['Notes'], ENT_QUOTES);


// check that customer_name and Vendor are both not empty
if ($customer_name == '' || $Vendor == '' || $MGMT_IP == '' || $Version == '' || $GUI_User == '' || $GUI_Pass == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'error: fill up required fields!';
renderForm($customer_name, $Vendor, $MGMT_IP, $Version, $GUI_User, $GUI_Pass, $Notes, $error, $customer_number);
}
else
{
// if everything is fine, update the record in the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE cloud_team SET customer_name = ?, Vendor = ?, MGMT_IP = ?, Version = ?, GUI_User = ?, GUI_Pass = ?, Notes = ?
WHERE customer_number=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssi", $customer_name, $Vendor, $MGMT_IP, $Version, $GUI_User, $GUI_Pass, $Notes, $customer_number);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user once the form is updated
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
// if the 'customer_number' variable is not valid_number, show an error message
else
{
echo "Error!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
else
{
// make sure the 'customer_number' value is valcustomer_number
if (is_numeric($_GET['customer_number']) && $_GET['customer_number'] > 0)
{
// get 'customer_number' from URL
$customer_number = $_GET['customer_number'];

// get the recod from the database
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cloud_team WHERE customer_number=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $customer_number);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($customer_number, $customer_name, $Vendor, $MGMT_IP, $Version, $GUI_User, $GUI_Pass, $Notes);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($customer_name, $Vendor, $MGMT_IP, $Version, $GUI_User, $GUI_Pass, $Notes, NULL, $customer_number);

$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
}
// if the 'customer_number' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the joomla_31/index.php/juniper page
else
{
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
else
{
renderForm();
}
}
// close the mysqli connection

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

[This is before editing the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7EyW.png)

[And this is after editing the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hItRM.png)

Comment: You need to UPDATE using the row primary key like `WHERE id=? AND customer_number=?`

Comment: Please post your table schema.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your WHERE clause is updating any record `WHERE customer_number=$customer_number`.

You need to further narrow your update to include a unique id such as `WHERE id=$id AND customer_number=$customer_number` if you only want to update one record.

Comment: Not an answer as it doesn't explain how to fix it

Comment: he never asked for a fix, seemed he was looking for an explanation of why

Comment: many thanks and i appreciate you answers!
the issue is that my table can have same multiple records ..
so how should i generate auto id per recordin the table and keep that id column hidden ?

Answer (score 0):

You're updating anywhere that the customer_number = $customer_number. You need to use a unique column from your table. Both customer's have the same number hence why both are changed.

So when updating, pick a column that is UNIQUE to a single row (ie Primary key) and use that to update the column. If you're not sure or don't have it, run a pre query to get the primary key or do a joint query like:

```
update xyz WHERE primary_key = '(select primary_key from table where customer_name = x AND date = Y )';   // Omit the ' ' if you are selecting a numeric value here
```

Comment: You should wrap column names in backticks. :)

Comment: I mean, in a good schema, the primary_key wouldn't be the reserved word or named primary_key, so... it's unnecessary

Comment: You're right but that doesn't include `xyz`, `customer_name`, `date` etc

Comment: xyz is also not a column, it's a stand in for entire update query I didn't type out and column names don't need backticks in an SQL query.

Comment: It's not "needed" per-say, but it is a very good habit to avoid ambiguity and to take it easy on the parser. Was just a suggestion anyways to make your answer better.

Comment: If you ever move the query from mysql, many other platforms don't allow backticks and actually will cause error in doing so.

Comment: But _using_ backticks in mysql queries again helps avoid ambiguity, and allows to much more control over your table column names etc. So many people recommend using backticks on column names on this site, I see it basically everywhere. You should use best practices for the code your are writing, not best practices for code you _may_ switch to later